Checkbox map checked from 2 arrays
I have an array that creates checkboxes, which works, but I also have another array which is constructed from a user array including the rights a user has. Now based on that second array, I want to have a checkbox shown checked if the user has that specific right.
Here is what I have:
return (
    <>
        {listOfRights.map((item, index) => {
            const roleChecked = userRoles.map((role) => role.RoleId === item.id);
            return <Form.Check
                key={index}
                inline
                name="userRights"
                isInvalid={!!errors.user_rights}
                label={getRightsTitle(item.roleName)}
                value={item.id}
                onChange={handleChange}
                id={`user_rights-${item.id}`}
                checked={roleChecked}
            />
         })}
    </>
)

listOfRights has all the rights, which shows the correct amount of checkboxes with each right. userRoles shows an array of:
[{
    id: 1,
    RoleId: 1,
    UserId: 1
}]

What now happens is that all the checkboxes are checked and not just the one having the right the user has.
What am I missing?

What happens if you const roleChecked = userRoles.map((role) => { console.log( role.RoleId ) )};  ??  Do you see all the role IDs in succession?

@Zak, yes it shows RoleId 1, three times

userRoles.map( ... ) produces an array of boolean values, and you then feed that whole array of booleans into checked={ ... }.
You most likely need to use some(), which produces a single boolean value:
const roleChecked = userRoles.some((role) => role.RoleId === item.id);


this works, the only issue I have, is that I am unable to make a checkbox checked when clicking on it, when I click on it, nothing happens. This is due to the: checked={roleChecked}

For that you'll have to write an onChange or onClick function in combination with state management. It's too much to discuss in comments, this might help: https://www.google.com/search?q=react+checkboxes+on+click+update+array

The answer here is in your one-liner.  You are setting your checkbox to a falsy "null" value instead of setting it to false  --  A "null" value is still a value, so it will check the box.
Instead you should be setting the checkbox to false, then mapping, using an if, then set to true if the IDs match.
Am I going to use a multiline so that it makes more sense:
const roleChecked = false;

userRoles.map((role) => {
    if (role.RoleId === item.id){
        roleChecked = true;
    }
)};

That should solve your falsy value and your checkboxes being mistakenly checked.

Why use map(), which produces an array of undefined values (in this case), which you then discard?

Well, sure ... It's just one way of doing it.  You could use a for as well.  for (var i=0; i < userRoles.length; i++) { and check userRoles[i].RoliId against item.id if one was concerned.  The overhead is negligible, but yes, creating an array you are never using can be seen as messy and wasteful.

The overhead will most likely be small indeed, I'm more concerned that it shows/teaches a bad understanding of when map() is to be used.
